# I wan to check that is my sql command containing the inputted data or not

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have two rounds "first and knock-out".Only the 4 team can go to knock-out round if they got the highest point on first round. Now firstly, I want to select that 4 team from first round and then check whether the inputted team is on the selected 4 team or not. Take a look to my code(So far i tried)
[In this image the two teams are marked should be exclude but when i giving condition it doesn't exclude those two teams]

[image]

```
$matches= new Match();
$matches->team1 = $request->input('team1');
$matches->team2 = $request->input('team2');

$ko =  DB::select('SELECT * FROM points WHERE round="first" ORDER BY points DESC , run_rate DESC LIMIT 4');

if($ko == $matches->team1 || $ko == $matches->team2) {
    $matches->round = "ko";
} else {
   $matches->round = "first";   
}
```

Screenshot of `$kos` after update.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `$ko` doesn't contain the results of the query until you pass it a closure, in this case `->first()`.

```
$ko =  DB::select('SELECT * FROM points WHERE round="first" ORDER BY points DESC , run_rate DESC LIMIT 4')->first();
```

Next, you need to compare the value of `$ko->team` to `$matches->team1` or `$matches->team2`:

```
if($ko->team == $matches->team1 || $ko->team == $matches->team2) {
  ...
}
```

Lastly, some clean up. The DB query can be simplified to use `Eloquent` syntax, instead of a raw `SELECT`:

```
$ko = DB::table("points")
->where("round", "=", "first")
->orderBy("points", "DESC")
->orderBy("run_rate", "DESC")
// ->limit(4) // Removing this; incompatible with `->first()`
->first();
```

There's another logic error; if you need to `limit(4)`, then you can't use `->first()`, you'd have to use `->get()`, which then creates a `Collection`, which can't be compared to `$matches` unless you loop:

```
$kos = DB::table("points")...->get();

$matches->round = "first";
foreach($kos AS $ko){
    if($ko->team == $matches->team1 || $ko->team == $matches->team2) {
        $matches->round = "ko";
        break;
    }
}
```

All in all, you need to reexamine what you're trying to do and read up on the Eloquent syntax, how to execute queries and return results, how to loop, access properties and compare those results, etc.

Edit: Since you're looping and comparing, set the default value of `$matches->round` to "first", then, while looping, if the compare condition is `true`, override `$matches->round` to "ko" and break out of the loop.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Lewis for you time, but when my in put is "$matches->team1=Barisal" and "$matches->team2=Rajshahi" then $matches->round shoul be "ko" but it save as "first"

Comment: Can you run a `dd($ko)` and tell me what it contains? (Edit the original question with that content please)

Comment: Heres what i get after dd($kos)

Comment: Yup, see my edit. When you loop and assign, the last value assigned is what sticks; you were likely assigning `$matches->round` to "ko" in one iteration, then overriding it to "first" in a later one.

Comment: yes i see it thank you brother it was saved my life....and also thanks for your time

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Please be sure to upvote this answer/accept it when you can so it can help others who have a similar problem.

Comment: If you have a new problem, post a new question. You can reference this one if you need to, but questions should be self-contained.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517650/how-to-check-that-inputted-data-is-in-foreach-or-not