# How to check that inputted data is in foreach or not?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two rounds "first and knock-out". Only 4 teams can go to knock-out round, those who got the highest point on the first round. Now firstly, I want to select that 4 teams from first round and then check whether the inputted team is on the selected 4 teams or not. Take a look to my code(So far I tried). My problem is, if I input two team names from below dd($kos) it will save the $matches->round="first"[Here I attach a dd($kos),if my inputted data is in the dd($kos) only then the $matches round="ko" else the $matches round="first"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PtPY.png)

```
$matches->round = "first";

$kos = DB::table("points")
    ->where("round", "=", "first")
    ->groupBy('team')
    ->orderByRaw('SUM(points) DESC')
    ->orderBy("run_rate", "DESC")
    ->limit(4)
    ->get();

 if(count($kos) > 0)
   {
    foreach($kos AS $ko){
     if($ko->team == $matches->team1 && $ko->team == $matches->team2) {
        $matches->round = "ko";
        break;
            }

         }
    }
```

Comment: Which is your input data.

Comment: As in the image of dd($kos) i got 4 team:Comilla, Khulna, Barisal,Rajshahi, when i input Comilla and Khulna it will save the $macthes->round="first" but it should save as $matches->round="ko"

Comment: So you want to update from "first" to "ko"?

Comment: yes...if the both team was from the dd($kos)

Comment: Your foreach loop eventually will return the same team $ko->team && $ko->team i assume?

Comment: sorry...Lim kean can you please tell me more elaborately????i cant understand your question clearly

Comment: I'm not sure as well but if you wanted to update the match round = 'ko' you need to throw the update code into your foreach loop.

Comment: Ok i will try and let you know.....