# Laravel's dd() only shows first iteration in foreach()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, dump, dd

I have sql command like

```
$kos = DB::select('SELECT team,round,SUM(points) AS total from points WHERE round="first" GROUP by team ORDER BY total desc, run_rate desc limit 4');
```

When I call `dd($kos)` it will give me this output [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jr0D.png), but when I run this:

```
$kos = DB::select('SELECT team,round,SUM(points) AS total FROM points WHERE round="first" GROUP by team ORDER BY total DESC, run_rate DESC LIMIT 4');
foreach($kos as $ko){
        dd($ko->team);
}
```

it will give me this output [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2oMn.png)

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: `dd` stands for dump & die, meaning it dumps the data, then kills the entire script.

Comment: so when you try to loop through, it only gets to 1 iteration, then it kills the scripts execution, meaning you never get to the second iteration

Comment: so there is any way to get the all team name which i got from dd($kos)

Comment: I think the confusion is not what `dd` does but what `DB::select` and `$ko->team` are or return.

Comment: @RobertRocha I think it's a fundamental misunderstanding of `Laravel` and `PHP`

Comment: try dump($ko->team) instead of dd() to don't kill entire code in loop

Comment: yes i have a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517650/how-to-check-that-inputted-data-is-in-foreach-or-not?noredirect=1#comment97746200_55517650 and i am trying to solve it but i can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dd`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-dd) will dump the passed value and exit the execution of the script

in first case you passed a collection to dd , it will dump the whole collection and stop execution of the script

in the second case you're in the first loop and dump the team value and stop execution

if you want just dump the value without stop the execution you should call [`dump`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-dump) function instead

try this

```
DB::select('SELECT team,round,SUM(points) AS total from points WHERE round="first" GROUP by team ORDER BY total desc, run_rate desc limit 4');
foreach($kos as $ko){
        dump($ko->team);
}
```

Comment: so there is any way to get the all team name which i got from dd($kos)